# I got errors when I use the MIRACL Cryptographic SDK

Tags: c++

In class ECn.h, has the definition:

```
friend BOOL operator==(const ECn& a,const ECn& b) {
    return epoint_comp(a.p,b.p);
}
```

We have defined a ECn as a member of class G2，when defined this statement:

```
friend BOOL operator==(G2& x,G2& y) {
    if (x.g==y.g) 
        return TRUE;
    else 
        return FALSE;
}
```

When I used VC6 to build my project，I got the error：

> error C2678: binary '==' : no operator defined which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const class ECn' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Why？ Pleas help me.

Comment: Are `ECn` and `G2` classes defined in the same namespace?

Comment: I didn't use namesapce, I included Ecn as header files.